# event listner prevent spaming clicking it

Tags: javascript

```
function attachEvent(element, event, callbackFunction) {
  if(element.addEventListener)  {
    element.addEventListener(event, function(){
      callbackFunction(this.getAttribute("src"));
    }, false);
  }
}

//start the function 
attachEvent(".Dicon", "click", handler);

function handler(){
console.log("stop");
}
```

i am using this function to ability my image click on function but i dont someone to keep spaming on one click on it , how do i prevent people keep spamming clicking it.

Comment: whats your question? No sure if I understood

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the element so the user will be visually shown it is un-clickable.

```
function attachClickEvent(element, handler) {
  if(typeof(element.addEventListener)=='function') {
    element.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
  }
}

function myClickEvent(e){
    try {           
        // disable the element by checking what element was clicked
        e.target.disabled=true;
        console.log("stopped (element disabled)");
    } catch (err){}
}

// start the function 
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Dicon");
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    attachClickEvent(elements[i], myClickEvent);            
}
```